# sqlite for xcode

Tags: xcode, sqlite

i have added an sqlite libsqlite3.0.dylib into my project's resources as per given in some tutorials. But there it says the size is 1.7MB but mine is just 360 KB and its getting an error like

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Why I am getting this error? is it because of the size difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 click your Project -> Build Settings.  Then under Build Options, there is an entry for Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C.  Choose Apple LLVM compiler 3.0
```